# C++ Prevent multiple inheritance of two classes by the derived classes of a certain class

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, multiple-inheritance

Kind of a verbose title, but here goes:

I have a situation where I want to prevent two classes from being derived by the same class or any class of a family.  In code:

```
    class A;
    class B;

    class C: public A; //Yes.
    class D: public B; //Yes.

    class E: public A, public B; //Yes.
    class F: public C, public B; //Yes.

    class G: public A /*Disallow inheritance of B at this point somehow*/;
    class H: public G, public B; //Error at this point...

    class I;
    class J: public G, public I; //...but not at this point.
```

It's a situation where the private members of A and B are to remain private from any derived classes, and friendship would ruin that design.  How would I be able to do this?

Comment: What problem are you solving where this design is the solution?

Comment: You should consider templated interfaces, type traits and concept checks to solve problems of such kind. Interface implementations may collide as ambiguous error messages.

Comment: @GManNickG I'm making a real time audio library that mimics concepts used in DAWs - I have two abstract classes Input and Output, and then I have another abstract class AudioSource, which is a template for classes that generate an audio output but take no input (like a sine wave generator or an audio file).  If I derive AudioSource and Input at the same time by accident (or someone else does), that goes against the definition of the class (and may have some bad effects down the road).  I could just document this, but it's even better if  I can forcibly prevent it from happening.

Comment: @g-makulik I thought templates might solve this, but the result would be kind of confusing looking unless I could hide it in the cpp somehow.  Does boost have something like this made already?

Comment: @user2228070: I see. Perhaps a class *could* be both an `Input` and `Output` provider? It might not make sense to model things like that but I think it might not be a fundamental problem to want to disallow.

Comment: @GManNickG I actually do have a class that inherits both - AudioEffect, which takes an input, modifies it, then sends an output to another input.  Prevention needs to start at AudioSource and continue infinitely down the family tree.

Comment: @user2228070 Why does `AudioEffect` class needs to realize input and output interfaces instead of just using and manipulating these?? IMHO you should try to decouple such processing classes from the data streaming.

Comment: @user2228070: That's my point, a class that is an `AudioEffect` could also be an `AudioSource`. It may not be realized in your program, but conceptually there's nothing *wrong* with it.

Comment: @GManNickG Have a class that provides an Audio Effect algo for an input stream and have an output stream as result, such it can be chained. That's your idea, right?

Comment: @g-makulik I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying to get rid of input and output altogether, or use them as components?

Comment: @g-makulik (Second comment) Yeah, that's basically what I'm doing.  It's exactly what FL Studio does, but I'm not sure if they represent it the same way (probably not).

Comment: @GmanNickG Well semantically that could be true, but I need a class that can't take input.  A generator won't be able to interpret input, for instance, and neither can a waveform loaded from an audio file.  FM Synthesizers might be a special case, but additive synthesizers don't do anything with input.  If I make weaker rules, it becomes harder to understand what each class is supposed to be.

Comment: @GManNickG Scratch that - I changed the defininition - now AudioSource generates an output without needing an input, which is different than not taking an input.  In that sense an AudioEffect is not an AudioSource, because the AudioEffect doesn't "create" sound, it manipulates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without really looking deeper, it looks like a typical problem that's used to be solved using static (compile time resolved) polymorphism.
The basic approach for such frameworks is the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) meta programming pattern (simply because you introduce a strong policy for your inheriting class in how your parent/base classes can be used or combined).

Have a look at how to provide

- [type traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/) (there are some libs available to support this before C++11 stdandard compliance)
- concept checks (several libs support this, e.g. [`boost::concept_check`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm))
- [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) and/or explicit (compile time) error conditions

You might consider various discrete client helper (API) classes to aggregate interface implementations for your final classes; this refers to hiding certain implementations in compilation units and eventually necessary factories for creation of concrete instances.